# Rails 4: how to insert line breaks in text_area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, posts

I have created a blog in rails. I'm a beginner and got quite far, but now I'm stuck with a seemingly minor detail: I can't seem to format the posts (articles).

Here's the relevant part of my show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= simple_format (@article.content) %>
</p>
```

When I write something and insert html-tags, they are not recognized as such. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rails will automatically remove html tags to prevent someone from injecting code into your webpage (e.g. malicious javascript)

If your users cannot enter data into `@article.content` and it's always safe then you can flag it as safe usng the html_safe method.

```
<%= (simple_format (@article.content)).html_safe %>
```

Comment: <%= simple_format @post.body %> works like a charm for me, thank you. However, now I can't seem to change the font size anymore. As soon as I put away the simple_format tag, I can adapt the font size again. 

Do you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Hi, I would think this is becuae `simple_format` is applying it's own styling classes.  You could try not using it!  `<%= @article.content.html_safe %>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the article content for reference? If I had to guess, I'd imagine Rails is escaping the html tags and inserting them as plain text (so the output looks like:  Article content !

Take a look at Rails' helper methods like content_tag (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) and concat (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat) and consider using those to help with generating the appropriate html tags.

An issue to be concerned with is who's going to be supplying the content. For example, if you're writing an application that other people will use, you want to make sure any html give you *is* escaped to avoid XSS attacks. In that case, you'll want to spend some time reading about how to properly sanitize user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can now specify the tag it gets wrapped in (defaults to `p`) like so:

```
  <%= simple_format (@article.content, {}, wrapper_tag: "div") %>
```

**or**

add `white-space: pre-line` style.

It will display \r or \n (enter) in user input as a new line.

for more info:
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format